# Share xamarin app with friend for testing

Tags: xamarin, uwp

thanks in advance.  I've been working on a Xamarin app that I hope to market before too long.  It's at the stage where I'd like to share it with one or 2 beta testers on Windows 10.  however, I am unable to run the app outside of Visual Studio (where it works fine).  When I try to click on the relevant debug or release .exe in Windows Explorer nothing happens.  How can I let my beta testers try it without having them install VS and giving them the entire project?

Comment: add some logging to determine why it doesn't run?

Answer (score 0):

If you have registered a Microsoft developer account and paid for it, then you can add your tester's Microsoft account to the console, then you upload your app to the console, they can see it in the store for testing.

Otherwise, you can make an offline bundle file using the visual studio publish wizard. For more info, see the [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps).